# HTML template not loading correctly without resizing browser window

Tags: jquery, html, css, templates, wow.js

I have used a portfolio html [(link is here)](https://ancient-oasis-74742.herokuapp.com/#home)template in my project.
It does not load as desired initially but when I resize browser window it 
loads perfectly.Can anyone guess where the issue can be.

Answer (score 0):

try to put your class

```
section aboutme fp-section active fp-table
```

to an height of

```
height: 100vh;
```

and put your class

```
fp-tableCell
```

also to an hight of

```
height: 100vh;
```

100vh means it will be as high as your window